# How to separate two strings by a line in python 3x

Tags: python-3.x

```
a='Kar shapath!'
b='Agneepath!'
print('''Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n'''+a*3 ,b*3)
```

How do I make `b` to show on the next line after `a`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

**Using Python f-string**

```
print(f"Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n{a*3} \n{b*3}")
```

**2. Using .format()**

```
print("Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n{} \n{}".format(a*3, b*3))
```

**Output will be same for both of the above solutions:**

```
Tu na thakega kabhi, 
Tu na thamega kabhi, 
Ek patra chhah bhi 
Kar shapath!Kar shapath!Kar shapath! 
Agneepath!Agneepath!Agneepath!
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sep="\n"` to the print function the `sep=` param defining the separation of different values that pass to the print function in this case `'''Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n'''+a*3` and `b*3`

```
print('''Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n'''+a*3 ,b*3, sep="\n")
```

Output

```
Tu na thakega kabhi, 
Tu na thamega kabhi, 
Ek patra chhah bhi 
Kar shapath!Kar shapath!Kar shapath!
Agneepath!Agneepath!Agneepath!
```

Answer (score 0):

Your either use the `.format()` function to be more robust.

```
a='Kar shapath!'
b='Agneepath!'
print('''Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n{} \n{}'''.format(a*3 ,b*3))
```

or use the stirng concatenation :

```
print('''Tu na thakega kabhi, \nTu na thamega kabhi, \nEk patra chhah bhi \n'''+a*3 ,'\n' + b*3)
```